# installing prehung doors ez-hang kits

Tags: doors, interior, door-frame

I'm going to be replacing many hollow core interior doors with solid core doors and I want to replace the jambs with VGDF (vertical grain doug fir) to match the doors, so I'm going with pre-hung doors to make it easier and faster.

I see these metal bracket kits, like EZ-Hang door installation kits. There are several brands and they all look the same. These kits look really easy to use and they are about $4-$5 a door.

Is there a down-side to these kits? I don't see anything negative about them. Anybody have any experience with these? Any tips to share? thx

Comment: If you're talking about [this product](https://ezhangdoor.com/), it says it "eliminates the need for shims", which seems like a pretty dubious claim for a solid core door.

Comment: No personal experience, but 20 years a carpenter and this looks like a terrible way to hang a solid door. Not even sure about hollow...

Comment: solid doors often have heavier duty jamb kits. are the portals in the framing big enough?

Answer (score 2):

They don't look particularly rigid, and solid doors are heavy. plastic wedges are cheap. wooden wedges are even cheaper (easy to make on a drop saw), I'd be putting wooden wegdes and panel adhesive ("no nails" etc) and nailing through the jamb and the wedges into the framing (before the glue sets)

Comment: I agree, and I tend to hide 3" screws through the jamb high and low behind the hinges as well (or replace two of the hinge screws with long ones). You don't want heavy doors tweaking your casing miters and throwing your alignment out of whack over time.